# How to get the intersected region(s) of multiple polygon layers

Tags: qgis, intersection

I have multiple layers with polygons.

[image: multiple polygons]

I want the regions that are intersected by *all* the polygons. The shared, common regions.

[image: shared region highlighted in red]

An example use case would be finding the shared area of multiple raster files if you had their footprints as polygons.

How can I achieve that with built-in QGIS tools?

Comment: **NOTE:** I will add an answer using merge, union, join, dissolve, extract right now but if you know an approach that is easier, please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge this requires multiple steps.

**Note**: This will give wrong results if you have overlapping polygons on one of your layers already.

[image: three layers]

1. **Merge vector layers** and select all the layers in question. This gives you one single layer to continue with. Also it adds a `layer` and `path` attribute to each feature to keep track of their provenience.

[image: merge]

[image: merged layer]

2. **Union** with no overlay layer. This results in a full "polygonisation": one polygon for each shared and non-shared region. The attributes are copied to each "child".

[image: union]

[image: unioned]

3. **Join attributes by location (summary)** to count the number of intersecting polygons per polygon:

   - Use the same layer as "Join layer".
   - Set the "Geometry predicate" to `equals`.
   - Enter the "Summaries to calculate" option and select `count`

This will count the unique occurances of each attribute field for each intersection. Since we had the `layer` attribute added by the merging tool, the `count` of this will be the number of polygons that intersect a specific region. This will have as many polygons per intersecting region as their are intersecting polygons.

[image: join]

[image: joined]

4. Dissolve the result to get rid of unnecessary duplicate polygons. Use `layer_count` as "Dissolve field(s)". Now we have one (multi-)polygon per unique value of `layer_count` / per intersecting region.

[image: dissolve]

[image: dissolved]

5. **Extract by expression** to extract the polygon with the highest count of intersections. This can be achieved with the expression `"layer_count" =  maximum("layer_count")`.

[image: extract]

Done!

[image: single polygon]

Comment: After the first step `Merge vector layers` - SAGA `Polygon self-intersection` tool may be of help.

Comment: Thanks! SAGA is not necessarily installed for a QGIS user though, I never had much luck with it on Linux. I would rather keep it all in QGIS and GDAL.